# MySQL performance on FreeBSD after moving db files from /var

Tags: mysql, freebsd, database-performance, jail

I was running out of space on /var so I moved my db dir to /usr and noticed a significate decrease in performance. In addition I noticed that performance is much slower as well under any Jailed systems, I'm assuming because they are also on /usr. It's all partitions on a single disk so it's not specific to any hd performance or anything. What are my solution options? Thanks!

**Output of tunefs on /var**

```
tunefs: POSIX.1e ACLs: (-a)                                disabled
tunefs: NFSv4 ACLs: (-N)                                   disabled
tunefs: MAC multilabel: (-l)                               disabled
tunefs: soft updates: (-n)                                 enabled
tunefs: gjournal: (-J)                                     disabled
tunefs: maximum blocks per file in a cylinder group: (-e)  2048
tunefs: average file size: (-f)                            16384
tunefs: average number of files in a directory: (-s)       64
tunefs: minimum percentage of free space: (-m)             8%
tunefs: optimization preference: (-o)                      time
tunefs: volume label: (-L)
```

I think my main concern is performance on my jails, with the only option being linking each one's /var onto the main /var further exacerbating my space issue.

**fstab**

```
# Device        Mountpoint  FStype  Options     Dump    Pass#
/dev/ad4s1b     none        swap    sw      0   0
/dev/ad4s1a     /       ufs rw      1   1
/dev/ad4s1e     /tmp        ufs rw      2   2
/dev/ad4s1f     /usr        ufs rw      2   2
/dev/ad4s1d     /var        ufs rw      2   2
/dev/acd0       /cdrom      cd9660  ro,noauto   0   0
```

Comment: Please edit into the question the file system's parameters. You can figure what partitions are mounted with the `df` command; then run those through `tunefs -p /dev/da0s1` (substitute your disk locations).

Comment: Paste the contents of your `/etc/fstab` you could have some rogue settings `diratime` or `atime` (quota/acls or anything else) on the `/usr` partition that is making things slower

Comment: Okay, I've added that.

Comment: Softupdates is turned on for `/var`, is it also turned on for `/usr`? It makes a difference in performance.

Comment: Yes, softupdates is enabled on usr

Comment: Maybe `/usr` and `/var` have different block sizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is your disk partitioned? If `/var` is closer to the centre of the platters than `/usr`, it will be quicker for the disk to perform seek operations under `/var` than under `/usr`; whether that alone is causing the performance loss, is debatable.

As for improving performance again, I'm not sure - is there anything else on `/var` you could move away to make room for your MySQL stuff to go back? Things like `/var/db/pkg`, `/var/db/portsnap` etc are good candidates here, since the tools that use them don't mind slow disk access times.

Comment: It is the default FreeBSD partition configuration. I've moved everything back onto /var but am getting closer to filling it up after clearing out as much as possible (log, etc). I think my main concern is performance on my jails, with the only option being linking each one's /var onto the main /var further exacerbating my space issue.

Comment: Looks like you've gone through file system config with Chris S already. If no differences show up there, then I wonder if either reinstalling with a rearranged partitioning scheme and/or adding a new disk (preferably on a different controller) might be possibilities? Both are a lot of work up front, but depending on your use case, may be worth the hit.

Comment: Thanks, This is on a production server w/ a decent load, so I think my best option for now is to just add another disk and configure my partitions differently during install in the future.